# Why do some Drush commands only run from docroot?

Tags: 8, drush

Wondering if anyone knows why some Drush commands (with file parameters) only run from the docroot and won't run from the project/composer root?

Commands such as `drush sql-query` and `drush locale-import` are among these.

For example, with standard Drupal folder structure:

/ (composer root)

- composer.json
- vendor
- translations

  - translations.fr.po
- web (docroot)

running from composer root:

- `vendor/bin/drush locale-import fr translations/translations.fr.po`

gives file not found error. Even using `./translations/translations.fr.po` gives same error

but going to docroot and running:

- `../vendor/bin/drush ../translations/translation.fr.po`

works fine.

Our deploy scripts always run `composer`, `drush` and other commands from the composer root folder. So a bit of a pain to have to `cd /web` and then `cd ..` for these couple "special" Drush commands. Guessing there must be something I am doing wrong.

Comment: IIRC Drush commands tend to run with the web root (not execution path) as the working directory -  does `vendor/bin/drush locale-import fr ../translations/translations.fr.po` from the project root work?

Comment: It might depend a on the version of Drush and the composer.json template you are using. Is the web root defined in composer.json? What version of Drush?

Comment: But in the end I think it's always safer to execute Drush commands from within the webroot.

Comment: @Clive, yes, that's the answer. I can run in project root but Drush still thinks of things as from docroot. Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure how to mark a comment as the answer :(

Comment: @liquidcms – You can add and accept that as answer yourself then to help future readers find the solution quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clive didn't post as an answer so I will just copy here:

Drush commands run as if from the web root (not execution path) as the working directory. So even though running command from the project root; argument paths have to be entered as if coming from the web root.

vendor/bin/drush locale-import fr ../translations/translations.fr.po

- from the project root

David's answer would also work if you were using aliases (which I am not).

Answer (score 0):

If you use a drush alias, it shouldn’t matter where you run the command from e.g

```
drush @site some-command
```

The webroot is specified in the alias.

More info https://www.drush.org/latest/site-aliases/

Comment: That's an alias to the site url. It won't have any impact on Drush not handling path to file arguments correctly.

Comment: @liquidcms The drush alias contains various settings including the webroot directory specified in the root setting eg “root: /other/path/to/live/drupal”